# How to do OnetoOne mapping and I don't want to save data to its related table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have 2 tables, vehicle and device

I want perform a post request in hibernate and doesn't want to save data in its corresponding device table. But I want to get the existing ID of device table and store into the vehicle table.
Could anyone help me with this?

```
@ENTITY
class vehicle{

@ID
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@OnetoOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Device deviceid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what does it mean "perform a post request" in this context, but you should pay attention on properties of "OneToOne" annotation. As you can see, you specified

```
@OnetoOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
```

cascade properties has javadoc

> (Optional) The operations that must be cascaded to the target of the
> association. By default no operations are cascaded.

In your case any of specified actions over "Vehicle" instance will trigger updating of "Device" instance (if it necessary).

Also by default "OneToOne" annotation has FetchType.EAGER.

> (Optional) Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

It means you will fetch "Device" entity when you fetch "Vehicle" entity from database. So hibernate will do 2 selects, something like that:

```
select * from vehicle where id = :id
select * from device where device_id = :id
```

Talk about, how hibernate map classes to database tables. Hibernate can map this structure to 2 tables.

```
create vehicle (
  id
  device_id
)

create device (
  id
  vehicle_id # if field "@OneToOne private Vehicle vehicle;" specified in "Device" class
)
```

Lastly, if you'd like to have only "deviceId" (not an object "Device") in "Vehicle" class, you should consider to take away @OneToOne and use something like

```
private Integer deviceId; // Without annotations
```

and manage it manually.
But in that case, don't forget to create foreign key constraints over relation "vehicle.device_id and device.id", it helps you to escape data inconsistency.